# Facebook Access Restricted (Bad IP)

Tags: facebook

Why can't I access my Facebook account? It says *Access restricted (Bad IP)*. How can I get it back? I already tried web proxies but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=288611514529252)

> You are trying to access Facebook from an IP (Internet Protocol) address that's associated with a misconfigured ISP (Internet Service Provider) or abusive behavior. If you think this is an error, please tell us more.

The page I linked is a form to fill out for Facebook to investigate your issue.